# How do you update a specific table column based on the value of another column of the same table?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 4 columns: A, B, C, D and one additional column: Index in a row.

Suppose I want to save a value of "50" but depending on the "Index" value of the row mysql will save 50 in either A, B, C, D. Say if Index=1 for that particular row, then 50 goes to column "A".

Is there a mysql query that will accomplish this all in one go? Or do I have to first read the index value, then make a switch statement with four different update queries to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET 
    A = CASE WHEN index = 1 THEN 50 ELSE A END,
    B = CASE WHEN index = 2 THEN 50 ELSE B END,
    C = CASE WHEN index = 3 THEN 50 ELSE C END,
    D = CASE WHEN index = 4 THEN 50 ELSE D END
WHERE ...
```

The query works by doing conditional value assignment to each column, according to the value of `index`. When a column does not need to be updated, its original value is simply reassigned, hence turning the operation to a no-op.